# using awk/sed to print text

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file abc.csv which has data in the following format-

```
mikayel, abc def ghi, acc, ma
michael, def ghi jkl, rcc, ma
michelle, mno pqr stu vwx, tyy, ma
monelle, yzq rty, gcc, ma
```

I want the second column as a list -

```
abc def ghi
def ghi kjl
mno pqr stu vwx
yzq rty
```

How do I do it using sed or awk?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}' file`?? I feel that this question must be a duplicated one. At least OP didn't do any google.....  but I am lazy to find the duplicated question and close the question........

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All assuming there is no `,` inside second field (escaped one), then it's possible with sed:

```
sed  's/[^,],[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*,*//' YourFile
```

and easier with awk:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' YourFile
```

But, if "*using sed or awk*" isn't a strong requirement, then it's better to use the tool designed for the job:

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 YourFile
```

Comment: cut works well. But the command that works is - 

    cut -d , -f 2 YourFile

Comment: both version of `cut` works here on my AIX and Linux (RHEL) which OS do you have ?

Comment: I am working on Linux. When I use the first version - i get an error - the delimiter must be a single character.

Comment: shell error i think. i use most often KSH and not bash maybe the reason

Comment: I want to save the results as seperate entries of a list. For example -             `[lindex $list 0] - abc def ghi`
`[lindex $list 1] - def ghi kjl`
 When I do it using sed or cut, I get all these as single seperate entries to the list.

Comment: reformat (sed or awk are perfect for that). In this case, used sed or awk for the first preparation. Reopen a new request (after cheking the question is not yet present)